# Time measuring of multiple CUDA kernels

Tags: cuda, gpu

How measure particular times of multiple CUDA kernels? I have tried this way.

```
   cudaEvent_t tic1, tic2, tic3, tic4;
   float time1, time2;
   cudaEventCreate(&tic1);
   cudaEventCreate(&tic2);
   cudaEventCreate(&tic3);
   cudaEventCreate(&tic4);

// launching the 1st kernel to execute on GPU
   cudaEventRecord(tic1, 0);
   kernel1<<<>>>(d_A, d_y, k, d_flag); 
   checkCuda( cudaPeekAtLastError() );  
   checkCuda(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

// calculating elapsed time on 2nd kernel               
   cudaEventRecord(tic2, 0);
   cudaEventElapsedTime(&time1, tic1, tic2);
   cudaEventSynchronize(tic2);

// launching the 2nd kernel to execute on GPU
   cudaEventRecord(tic3, 0);
   kernel2<<<>>>(d_A_sys, d_y_sys, k, d_flag); 
   checkCuda( cudaPeekAtLastError() );  
   checkCuda(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

// calculating elapsed time on 2nd kernel            
   cudaEventRecord(tic4, 0);
   cudaEventElapsedTime(&time2, tic3, tic4);

   cudaEventSynchronize(tic4);
```

I am getting the first result correct. But for the 2nd kernel, time shows zero.

Comment: Just use Nvidia's Visual Profiler. It's easy to use, has many options and you can save your results for future use.

Comment: put each call to `cudaEventSynchronize()` before the preceding call to `cudaEventElapsedTime()`.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Crovella. Now it works.  I am using CUDA 7.0 toolkits on a Tesla K80, installed in  remote server. I always want to use Visual Profiler but don't know how to use. If anyone can help me.

Comment: Thanks @Zindarod for helping.

Answer (score 1):

To make complex (and accurate) measurements of times and durations, you should not rely on CUDA events, but rather use nVIDIA's profiling mechanism, and its profiler application nvprof, or with the visual profiler application nvvp.

Read this article on the Parallel4All blog:

[CUDA Pro Tip: nvprof is Your Handy Universal GPU Profiler](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-nvprof-your-handy-universal-gpu-profiler/)

Basically, you start the visual profile, load the executable, set the command-line arguments and produce a graphical timeline you can browse; it would look something like this:

[image]

or you run your executable with nvprof enabled (not using the visual profiler), and it will produce things like a csv/xml listing of all kernel execution times, CUDA API calls etc., and/or a profiling results file which can then be opened in the visual profiler.

Comment: "you should not rely on CUDA events, but rather use nVIDIA's profiling mechanism", depends if you are measuring for development and performance tests or to inform user at runtime. The OP doesn't specify his goal